# Python search list for variable & return matching elements

Tags: python, list, search, match

I am attempting to provide a function in python that will search a list based on user input and return all matching rows within that list.

For example if the user types in hello it will return any occurrence of hello in that list.

So far I have this:

```
if(prefixes in list):
        matching = [s for s in list if prefixes in s]
        for release in matching:
            name = release.lstrip('rd').rstrip('xml').lstrip('-').rstrip('.')
            path = rdDirectory+release
            print '%-40s  %s' % (name, path)
```

I am new too python so any help will be gratefully accepted

Input = :

```
./tpupdate.py -l asterix  where asterix = search variable
```

Output =

```
Available Releases                         Path
asterix-1.0.0-production
zebedee-3.2.1-production
```

etc...

The problem: It doesnt return based on the user in-putted prefix and returns all elements of list

Comment: How does your list look like? Can you show a sample input, and output?

Comment: You gave us some code, but you didn't say how it doesn't work. What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do? If it gives the wrong output, give an example with the right output. If it gives an error, post it in full with the stack trace.

Comment: `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` do not remove a full string. They remove *each of the characters named*. `.rstrip('xml')` does *not* mean 'remove the string `'xml'` from the end', it means 'remove the characters `'x'`, `'m'` and `'l'` from the end' instead. `some-sentence-with-lxmmmmlx` would have `lxmmmlx` removed.

Comment: show yuor `print release ` output